# How to use form.submit with jQuery validate and overlay windows

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have figured out how to submitHandler and do some tasks before submitting the form. Now I need to show a few overlay windows (jQuery Tools) and onClose, submit the form. But its not working, Im getting a ton of errors in Firebug.

Anyone have any ideas, here is my code:

```
$("#frmcheckout").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {

    // Before Submit - show compliance messages
    var state = $('#shippingState1').val();

    if(state == 'CT' || state == 'Connecticut' || state == '1049'){
        $("#compliance-order-ct").overlay({
        expose: {
        color: '#333',
        loadSpeed: 200,
        opacity: 0.9
        },
        closeOnClick: false,
        load: true,
        onClose: function() { 
          // Submit the form
          console.log('overlay closed');
          form.submit();
          //return true; 
        }
        });
    }

});
```

If I bypass using the overlay, I'm able to use form.submit just fine - but once I include it in onClose event, then it doesn't submit. Just seeing if anyone sees anything glaring.

Comment: is it possible the errors might explain the issue?

Comment: you just changed you code, but make no mention of an update?? have you added a breakpoint on the onClose function to see whats happening? once again, what are some of the "tons of errors", they probably would point you in some direction (ie  'submit() is not a function')

Comment: Sorry about that - I changed the code slightly. Let me debug a little further.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure without the errors and you only say its 'not working' (does the overlay not show up, or does the form not submit?)

...but I can say that onClose will not receive the form object as a param, it will get an Event. So you are probably trying to call `submit` on an Event Object, not the form.

From the jQuery tools [docs](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html):

> All event listeners receive the Event Object as the first argument and
>   there are no other arguments for Overlay.

Comment: I have a feeling its a scope issue, since I pass the form DOM element into the jQuery submitHandler, but then the onClose event handler isn't aware of the form element. Does that make sense?